# easy way of keeping tracks of id when quicksorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

I have an array of points, that matches with my array of dataID.

```
     points = [[2,3.5], [1,2.7], [5,2.21], [2,351]];
     dataID = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

The quicksort function, in javaScript, Im using is:
(with my own compare function that compares by X then Y, and works)

```
    quicksortbyXthenY: function(array){
    if(array.length <= 1) return array;
    var pivot = array.splice(Math.round(array.length/2),1)[0];
    var lower = greater = [];
    jQuery.each(array, function() {
        if(compare(this, pivot)>=0){
            lower.push(this);
        }else{
            greater.push(this); 
        }
    });
    return (quicksortbyXthenY(lower).concat([pivot])).concat(quicksortbyXthenY(greater));
```

I need to know the new order of the points, i.e. an updated array of the dataID that matches correct with the new order of points.

What is the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Why are you using two separate arrays instead of a single array of objects? Perhaps something like this: `[{id:1,p:[2,3.5]},{id:2,p:[1,2.7]},...]` - or `[{id:1,x:2,y:3.5},...]`.

Comment: Why are you implementing quicksort on your own instead of using the native `sort` method? Yours seems to be much less efficient; also I don't see what `byXthenY` would mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know the new order of the points, i.e. an updated array of the dataID that matches correct with the new order of points.

Give the arrays their ids, then sort them, then extract the ids from the sorted array:

```
for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++)
    points[i].dataID = dataIDs[i];
points.sort(compare);
for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++)
    dataIDs[i] = points[i].dataID;
```

Comment: perfect, it was something as easy as that I was looking for